# How to remove padding from horizontal barchart of mpandroidchart?

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am trying to make a horizontal barchart that covers the entire parent layout but its not. Below is my code -

```
HorizontalBarChart barchart = new HorizontalBarChart(activity);
barchart.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 110, weight));

ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
entries.add(new BarEntry(86.0f, 0));

BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "");
dataset.setColor(Color.parseColor("#E0E0E0"));

ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
labels.add("86.0"); 

BarData bardata = new BarData(labels, dataset);
barchart.setData(bardata);
barchart.setDescription("");

Legend legend = barchart.getLegend();
legend.setEnabled(false);

YAxis topAxis = barchart.getAxisLeft();
topAxis.setDrawLabels(false);

YAxis bottomAxis = barchart.getAxisRight();
bottomAxis.setDrawLabels(false);

XAxis rightAxis = barchart.getXAxis();
rightAxis.setDrawLabels(false);
bottomAxis.setDrawLabels(false);

barchart.setPadding(-1, -1, -1, -1);
barchart.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

return barchart;
```

I want my horizontal barchart (barchart) to fill the entire blue area. Can someone please help.

EDIT : @PhilippJahoda i tried your solution, but at first launch it shows up the same way it was, when i click/touch the chart then only it covers the entire area. Can you please tell me why i have to touch the chart to make it fill the entire space.

At first launch it looks like -

Screen shot: [image]

After clicking it looks like -

Screen shot2: [image]

Answer (score 27):

Update to the latest version of the library if you have not already.
Then, just **remove all offsets** from the chart. It's in the [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport).

Call:

```
chart.setViewPortOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
```

Comment: It's the same problem I'm having. I'm calling chart.setViewPortOffset(100f, 0f, 100f, 0f) after setting chart Data.. but my edit takes effect only after I tap on the chart. Any solution @PhilippJahoda? I've got the latest mpchart lib version.

Comment: Don't have method setViewPortOffsets for piechart

Comment: @SANAT try using setExtraOffsets with negative values

Comment: For some reason, setViewPortOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f) not working in API<24

Comment: setViewPortOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f) only works well when it's all zeroes. If you try something like setViewPortOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 10f) it won't work until interaciton with the chart. Even if you call invalidate().

Answer (score 12):

The padding removal works with

```
chart.setViewPortOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
```

but if the effect appears only after touch, try to invalidate chart view (after you set data) this way:

```
post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        chartView.invalidate();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    YAxis yl = chart.getAxisLeft();
    yl.setSpaceTop(20f);
```

Answer (score 3):

Best way to control the padding what I feel is as:

1. Set all the offsets to 0

   chart.setViewPortOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
2. Control the padding from the XML

   com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

Answer (score 0):

When you first set your ViePortOffsets and after that moveViewTo then it works.

```
Graph.setViewPortOffsets(0F,0F,0F,0F)
Graph.moveViewTo(0f,0f,YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT)
Graph.invalidate()
```